# How to get the floored quotient of two integers?

Tags: rust

I have two `u64`s and I would like to divide them and take the floor of the result. (Since these are unsigned, floor and round towards zero is the same.)

How can I do this?

Comment: I know this may seem like an overly simple question, but I actually did spend like 10 minutes searching for this because I assumed the default was round towards nearest even.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[impl Div<i32> for i32](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html#impl-Div%3Ci32%3E) documentation says:

> This operation rounds towards zero, truncating any fractional part of the exact result.

It applies to all integer types:

```rust
macro_rules! div_impl_integer {
    ($($t:ty)*) => ($(
        /// This operation rounds towards zero, truncating any
        /// fractional part of the exact result.
        #[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
        impl Div for $t {
            type Output = $t;

            #[inline]
            fn div(self, other: $t) -> $t { self / other }
        }

        forward_ref_binop! { impl Div, div for $t, $t }
    )*)
}

div_impl_integer! { usize u8 u16 u32 u64 u128 isize i8 i16 i32 i64 i128 }
```

Therefore, all you need to do is divide normally.

```rust
assert_eq!(3/2, 1);
assert_eq!(9/4, 2);
```

Comment: Mark this as an answer, so it disappears from the list of unanswered questions, thanks!